# Problem debugging web part on SharePoint 2010 beta and Visual Studio 2010 beta

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a "Hello World" web part. When I pressed F5 in Visual Studio 2010, I got the following error. I have already got Microsoft SharePoint Foundation User Code Service started. Can anyone shine some light on this?

I do not see Microsoft SharePoint Sandboxed code service in my Central admin nor after running the powershell command "Get-SPServiceInstance | format-table TypeName, Id".Is it possible I have overlooked something when I install SharePoint 2010 beta?How Can I install the service and start the service?

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unable to attach. Process 'SPUCWORKERPROCESS.exe' is not running on 'WIN-MP9OQOTCKB2'.

Do you want to continue anyway?
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to debug your web part? If so, can't you just attach the debugger to the w3wp.exe process and set a breakpoint in your code?

If you aren't trying to debug it, what exactly are you looking to do? If you want to use your web part, deploy it from VS and then go to the SP site and add your web part.

EDIT
After re-reading this, it appears you may be trying to deploy a Visual Web Part as a sandboxed solution. You cannot do this. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335711.aspx. You can do 1 of 2 things, change your Visual Web Part to just a Web Part, or change your solution to not be deployed as a sandboxed solution. You can do this by setting the project property (SandboxedSolution) to false.

Comment: I do use just a Web Part,my problem is that when I try to dubug ,I got an error saying Process 'SPUCWORKERPROCESS.exe' is not running on my machine.
I have used google.bing.com ,I have been told to start Microsoft SharePoint Sandboxed code service,but I could not find it in either central admin nor Services.

Comment: This quote comes directly from the above link: "Visual Studio automatically attaches the debugger to this process when you press F5. If you are debugging a solution that’s already deployed, you need to attach to this process manually." This quote is referring to the SPUCWorkerProcess.exe.

Comment: I know mate ,but I got an error when I press F5,which says SPUCWorkerProcess.exe is not running.You are not helping.

Comment: please see this blog for answer http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/process-spucworkerprocess-exe-is-not-running/